# Manage large object graph creation in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, persistence

I have a object model like Document->Section->Value but Value can also be a table type so I then have Value->Row->Column->Value. So worst case is Document->Section->Value->Row->Column->Value which can result in a lot of objects.

When I receive an update from my backend I need to inflate the received JSON into CoreData objects and save it which can be time consuming. To make matters worse there may be a large queue of updates pending if the user has been offline which can take many minutes or longer to catch up.

As an example I set some timers to try and locate a 'worst case' transaction and found a single document update taking 1.3 seconds. This document contained 5 sections, 2 rows, 14 columns and 425 values. That is a lot of object creation and I'm not surprised it takes a while. The question is how can I improve this?

I am thinking of moving to a blob-ish type storage where the document object maintains its own properties as it does now, but all the content objects just become a large dictionary. Should make the updates a lot faster with only one object for CoreData to create and save.

I would then just need to inflate it into a temporary object graph to display and interact with in the UI. Is this a good approach or is there a better option?

Realm has also been suggested to me, but I would imagine it would also get bogged down with so many nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your objects on a background thread.  It might not be quicker but it will at least allow your main thread to remain active, including the UI.  You can easily do this by creating a temporary managed object context that has a different queue priority to your main managed object context.  Heres some example code :

```
NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
tmpContext.parentContext = [CoreDataManager sharedManager].managedObjectContext;  //my main managed object context - this might be on your appdelegate (for me its on a singleton)
[tmpContext performBlock:^
{
    //Im also using JSON - my json has been converted into a dictionary, then arrays
    NSArray *libraries = [templatesDict objectForKey:@"array"];
    if (libraries)
    {
        //create some objects here using the temporary context, eg:
        AnswerObject *newAnswer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kCoreDataAnswer inManagedObjectContext:tmpContext];
    }

    // push to parent managed object context
    NSError *error;
    if (![tmpContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"!!!!!! error saving background context");
    }

    // save parent to disk asynchronously
    [[CoreDataManager sharedManager].managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
        if (![[CoreDataManager sharedManager].managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"!!!!!!error saving main context");
        }
    }];

    //and thats the temp context saved to the main
}];
```

Alternatively, Can I suggest you just do not save it to coredata at all?  Might sound stupid, but this can be a good idea.  I work professionally for a company that creates apps that process large volumes of JSON, then creates 'answer' objects and sends those back to the server.  While we do create coredata objects for data that will return to the server, we do NOT create coredata objects to represent the json.  Instead we just leave the JSON in an NSDictionary.  You can save NSDictionaries to coredata if you need to, to a parent object for eg, quite simply now.  NSDictionaries are perfectly quick enough for your needs, and all that data processing in creating coredata objects might actually not improve your app at all.  Not doing this in our case has saved us enormous time in the long run.

Comment: I am already doing this on a background thread otherwise the UI would be completely useless haha. The speed is my issue. Keeping all the data in an NSDictionary is the 'blob-ish' approach I was thinking of

Comment: NSDictionaries are much better suited to JSON in a key way : when your JSON changes, which it might, you dont need to worry about changing your data structure.  NSDictionaries are as quick and versatile as JSON is, which makes them ideally suited to each other.  While it might seem the proper way, putting your JSON into coredata, actually it might cost you lots of dev time in the long run.  And theres no speed issue with NSDictionary.